# As a recent graduate, what is my "current occupation" for a Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

I just graduated from my university and am accepted in a Summer School in Hungary related to my studies, for two weeks. I'm going to apply for a Schengen visa.

What should I mention as my occupation since I've graduated and I can't have proof of ongoing studies?

Does this affect the visa process?

Answer (score 2):

You have recently graduated and are now applying for a Schengen visa in order to take courses in Hungary.

> I'm gonna apply for a Schengen visa but what should I mention as my
>   occupation since I graduated and I can't have a proof of ongoing
>   studies?

You can put down "Prospective Student"

> and does this affect the visa process?

*Everything* you put down on the application affects the outcome, and 'Occupation' is no different.  Your 'occupation' tells them what to look for in assessing your personal circumstances, so don't over-decorate your occupation beyond what it actually is or they will worry if you are presenting yourself accurately.

"Prospective Student" is fine.

Comment: How about "postgraduate student"?

Comment: @o.m., please elevate your comment to an answer so that it has more visibility

Comment: @JohnMicheal please read how the site works to assure you always get quality answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you have a master or PhD you should call yourself postgraduate student rather than just student. In parts of Europe postgrads are seen as junior scientists, not *merely* students.